# Grep entire line after word

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

What would be the grep command to get an everything in the line after a match?
For example on a file path:

```
/home/usr/we/This/is/the/file/path
```

and I want the output to be

```
/we/This/is/the/File/Path
```

Matching the /we as the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -o` does what you want.

```
grep -o '/we.*'
```

Comment: (As for why it does what the OP wants, the option `-o` prints only the matching part of the line, instead of the whole line, `/we` is the desired beginning of the match, and `.*` matches any number of any character causing the match to include everything after `/we`.)

Answer (score 1):

```
YourInput | sed 's|/home/usr\(/we.*\)|\1|'
```

assuming it's always (and only) starting with /home/usr 
else

```
YourInput | sed -n 's|^.*\(/we.*\)||p'
```

return only line(s) having /we and remove text before `/we`

Comment: Does not use `/we` as a search trigger as requested by OP

Comment: sorry, i modify the answer

Answer (score 1):

OP like to use `we` as a trigger.  Using `awk`

```
awk -F/ '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {if ($i~/we/) f=1;if (f) printf "/%s",$i}print ""}' file
/we/This/is/the/file/path
```

Using `gnu awk`

```
awk '{print gensub(/.*(\/we)/,"\\1","g")}' file
/we/This/is/the/file/path
```